# How to change the background color of the div while focusing the text Input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-color

In render,

```
 <div id="container" tabindex="0">
    <input id = "input" type="text" />
  </div>
```

In css,

```
#container::focus{
 background-color: "red"
}
```

I need to make the bg-clr to be fixed in the div when focusing the input field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) CSS pseudo-class

> The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has
> received focus or contains an element that has received focus.

```css
#container:focus-within {
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" tabindex="0">
  <input id="input" type="text" />
</div>
```

**Note:** if you don't want to focus `div#container` directly remove `tabindex`

Comment: `:focus-within` isn't cross-browser compatible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve isn't possible by css. You need use JavaScript `focus` and `blur` event listeners on the `input` to change the background color of `div`:

```
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    e.target.closest("#container").classList.add('focus');
})
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    e.target.closest("#container").classList.remove('focus');
})
```

CSS:

```
#container.focus{
 background-color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an onfocus event to the element then

```
 <div id="container" tabindex="0">
    <input id = "input" type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)" />

<script>
function myFunction(item) {
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>
```

See this page for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use the **JavaScript**, this one can be the one solution. Based on the requirement you can se the color into **Focus** and Blur event.

```js
$(document).on('focus','.input', function() {
$("#container").css("background-color","black");
})

$(document).on('blur','.input', function() {
$("#container").css("background-color", "white");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <input class="input" id="input" type="text" />
  </div>
```